# Create /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2 with exact size

Tags: debian, fdisk

How is possible to create `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2` with size of `20GB`? I was lurking over google and tryed:

```
Partition type
   p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
   e   extended (container for logical partitions)
Select (default p): p
Partition number (1-4, default 1): 1
First sector (2048-286677119, default 2048): 
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-286677119, default 286677119): +size 20G
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-286677119, default 286677119): 

Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux' and of size 136.7 GiB.
```

but it again created with full size of `136.7 GiB`.

Comment: How exact, does it need to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see how the instructions are confusing; you need to enter

```
+20G
```

at the prompt, not `+size ...`.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you post the syntax of size is incorrect, you must omit the word "size", the size you must enter is:  +20G